# Questions regarding JtaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

I am looking for a way to put CRUD of two data source into one transaction by Spring/JTA, but have following questions:

1. Is it ok that the `datasource` is is made of`org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` instead of JNDI?
2. There are two parameters to intitiate a JtaTransactionManager:

   ```
   public JtaTransactionManager(UserTransaction userTransaction,
                        TransactionManager transactionManager)
   ```

   From [Spring document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html#JtaTransactionManager%28javax.transaction.UserTransaction,%20javax.transaction.TransactionManager%29):

   ```
   userTransaction - the JTA UserTransaction to use as direct reference
   transactionManager - the JTA TransactionManager to use as direct reference
   ```

   If I have a datasource `DS_A` and another datasource `DS_B`, which both requires within the same transaction manager, then which should be the `UserTransaction` and how to define the `TransactionManager`, as I am just creating the JtaTransactionManager, does it mean another JtaTransactionManager? Also it looks both parameters are not required so how JtaTransactionManager can detect them from:

   ```
   <context:annotation-driven/>
   <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
   ```
3. If everything is well defined in application context, then which transaction manager bean should referred in `@Transactional` annotation, if there are two datasources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it ok that the datasource is is made oforg.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource instead of JNDI?

JNDI is just a way to access the datasource. To have distributed transactions across databases you need to use transactional data sources. For e.g. microsoft sql server jdbc driver has a transactional data source - `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource`.

> 2. If I have a datasource DS_A and another datasource DS_B, which both requires within the same transaction manager, then which should be the
>      UserTransaction and how to define the TransactionManager, as I am just
>      creating the JtaTransactionManager, does it mean another
>      JtaTransactionManager?

JtaTransactionManager is an implementation for JTA, delegating to a backend JTA provider. So you would need a JTA provider that implements distributed transactions. [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm) is one such JTA provider. There are various configurations needed

a. hibernate.properties

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
<property name="useTransactionAwareDataSource" value="true"/>
```

b. Defining transaction manager and usertransaction beans

```
    <bean id="BitronixTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
          class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="bitronixConfiguration"
          destroy-method="shutdown">
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"                           class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="BitronixTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="BitronixTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

c. Transaction Interceptor and annotation support

```
    <bean id="annotationTransactionSource"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>


    <bean id="transactionInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref local="transactionManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
            <ref local="annotationTransactionSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Spring 3.1 also introduced a `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation so another way to configure would be

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
      ...
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
      //configure JTA transaction manager
      return transactionManager;
   }
}
```

> 3. If everything is well defined in application context, then which transaction manager bean should referred in @Transactional annotation,
>      if there are two datasources?

I assume the above explanation should answer this question. There is just one transaction manager managing transactions over the two data sources. These are called distributed transaction and they use a two phase commit protocol. Go through [this](http://www.yusufaytas.com/xa-transactions-a-simple-guide/) link for an introductory article on XA transactions.

Comment: That's great answer, thank you! Just one remaining question to `Transaction Interceptor and annotation support`, is it a solution prior to Spring 3.2 so that the version afterward using `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` can do the same? And is it necessary to do any explicit declare of the transaction manager other than quoted in @Transactional annotation?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the java way of configuring transaction manager and annotation support. For the second question, yes you would have to explicitly declare a transaction manager.